# Why to use fixed regressor in Breusch-Pagan?

Tags: r, time-series, heteroscedasticity

I need to use Breusch-Pagan to check heteroscedasticity of my timeseries.

I found the explanation of the function, here: http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/lmtest/html/bptest.html

Looking at the example, I saw that the regressor is a simple serie with 1 -1 repeated values. Could someone explain me why ?

Do I have to use fixed values on the regressor?

However if I have a vector(R vector) that I would test for heteroscedasticity I could do:

```
x <- rep(c(-1,1), 375)
mySerie <- rnorm(750)
mySerie <- 1 + x + mySerie
bptest(y ~ mySerie)
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breusch%E2%80%93Pagan_test

Comment: @whuber ? I have read it I'm asking if i can use that pattern 1 -1because I'm testing the residuals of a linear regressions

Comment: The R manual page merely provides an illustration using synthetic data.  The Wikipedia article explains the test in general.

Comment: @whuber I don't understand what you are asking me. I know how BP test works (less or more) BUT i have a doubt about WHAT variable to use AS regressor because if i use two prices (i use the return in % of prices) maybe they can influence themself so I don't know what formula shoulbe be better (more sense) to use... could you help me?

Comment: I'm not asking anything.  The Wikipedia article is quite clear about what the regressors are in the BP test.  Your mention of two prices in the previous comment does not seem to have any connection with the question itself.  Have you perhaps forgotten to mention some important things about what you're trying to do?

Comment: @whuber excuse me, I mean "answer" not "ask" eheh, I need to understand if the variance of the residuals of my regression have a constant variance during all the period.with constant variance i mean that if the variance is "1" this variance have to be 1 in all the series (less or more)